# Minimize Keyboard Button not recognized as Back Button

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, sony, sony-xperia

Using `log.d` and a function as :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Log.d("back","back");
    }
}
```

It seems, the button to minimize the keyboard is not recognized as the back button. Is there a workaround to find a keyID for this button, or does it actually exist and am I doing something wrong?

Device Used : Xperia Z1 C6902

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do whatever you want to do
        return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Refer [Back and other keys](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html). But if onBackPressed is not working, also try to implement onKeyDown method where you handle keycode for back.

Comment: It still does not recognize the minimize button as a back button keypress. The minimize button in reference here is the one circled in : http://i.imgur.com/bZ55FWn.jpg